# How to customize terminal server so that users can only save data to their home directory?

Tags: windows-server-2008, terminal

I'm new to terminal servers and would like to customize my users' environments so that they save all their files to their home directories.  I don't want them to have my documents or any other folders on their terminal server session other than their home folders.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: You could try Profile Acceleration Technology with roaming profiles from Tricerat... haha

Answer (score 2):

You need to make copious use of Group Policies to enable folder redirection + roaming profiles.

You can redirect Desktop, Documents, and Favorites to their home folder (or another share if you don't want it to use their home folder).

I would however advise not redirecting Application Data.  Windows stands on this and you will notice a performance hit.  Using roaming profiles should address that folder.

This is not a silver bullet though.  Occasionally a profile will get out of whack and need to be renamed.  Folder redirection only works properly when redirected to a local folder on the same LAN.  Don't redirect it to a location that is on the other side of a low speed wan link.

Chapter 4 "Creating the user work environment" of the Windows 2008 Terminal Server Resource Kit is an excellent how-to guide:

[http://www.amazon.com/dp/0735625859](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735625859)